# SQL update table data query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run update query to update PercentAvailability column value 0 to 100 between specified date period in my case `2012-10-28 03:31:01 to 2012-10-28 08:31:01`. see following picture.

[image]

How do i run query to update above data between specified date?

Note: I have many ApplicationID which has this issue so how could i run query against all ApplicationID, I believe we need to run JOIN syntax but it would be good if you give some short of hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this query

```
update your_table
set PercentAvailability = 100
where PercentAvailability = 0
and [DateTime] between '2012-10-28 03:31:01' and '2012-10-28 08:31:01'
```

or if you want to update the same thing only for a specific `ApplicationID` then do

```
update your_table
set PercentAvailability = 100
where PercentAvailability = 0
and [DateTime] between '2012-10-28 03:31:01' and '2012-10-28 08:31:01'
and ApplicationID = 1235
```

or for multiple `ApplicationID` do

```
update your_table
set PercentAvailability = 100
where PercentAvailability = 0
and [DateTime] between '2012-10-28 03:31:01' and '2012-10-28 08:31:01'
and ApplicationID in (1235, 1236, 1237)
```

or for a big number or `ApplicationID` you could do a subquery

```
update your_table
set PercentAvailability = 100
where PercentAvailability = 0
and [DateTime] between '2012-10-28 03:31:01' and '2012-10-28 08:31:01'
and ApplicationID in (select ApplicationID from another_table where somecondition)
```

Comment: what about ApplicationID ? if i just want to run against specific one for TEST

Comment: Then just add an `and ApplicationID = 1235` to the end of the query.

Comment: You guys are super nice!! How do i run it against all my ApplicationID ?? How do i match ALL?

Comment: If you want to update all to 100 percent then just leave the complete `where` clause. Or if you want to update all to 100 percent that are 0 percent then run `update your_table
set PercentAvailability = 100
where PercentAvailability = 0`

Comment: Ah! you didn't get my question. I have many ApplicationID like 1235, 1236, 1237 so on... How do i run this same query against all in one shot? I don't think ApplicationID = * work :(

Comment: Okay, that is totally fine, and it works!! But my question is how do i run same SQL code for multiple ApplicationID ??? we have total 200 applicationID do i manually run this code against 200 ID? or is there any work around ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18878/discussion-between-juergen-d-and-satish)

Comment: Cool! This is what i was looking - and ApplicationID in (select ApplicationID from your_table where somecondition)